# Why does mutual SSL require a key pair on the client side instead of just a public certificate?

Tags: security, ssl

I'm doing my best to understand **mutual** SSL. One question I can't find a good answer to is why you need to create a key pair on the client instead of just providing a public client certificate.

So far I understand the following (very oversimplified):

Regular SSL:

- The server has a key pair and sends the public part (certificate) so the client can use that public key to encrypt messages so they can share a symmetric key and eventually secure all communication.
- To verify that the server is actually the server the issuer of the certificate has to be trusted (in a truststore) of the client by default.

Mutual SSL:

- Exactly the same, only this time the server asks the client to authenticate itself.
- The client sends its public certificate, which is verified against some kind of list of "known certificates" on the server. If it matches, communication can continue.

I don't understand why I have to include the entire key pair (the private part as well) in the key store I use on the client side. Where is the client's private key used in the process?

Comment: The key pair is required so that the client can sign the `CertifcateVerifyMessage` with its private key, so that the server can establish that the client owns the certificate, and the certificate is required because that's what the sever asked for, so that some client-identifying information in an accepted form is provided. The client does not use the server's publicly key to encrypt messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The server has a key pair and sends the public part (certificate) so the client can use that public key to encrypt messages so they can share a symmetric key and eventually secure all communication.

That's not the main point of the server certificate and with modern key exchange methods (i.e. Diffie-Hellman) the certificate is not involved at all in the key exchange. What you describe is only true for the obsolete RSA key exchange.

The main point of the certificate is to be used for authentication. Authentication means that the **server proves that it owns the provided certificate** and then that the client verifies that the certificate matches its expectations, i.e. issued by a trusted CA, expected subject/SAN, not expired etc.

The **proof of ownership is done by signing some data** (which is at least in part provided by the peer, i.e. client) **with the private key** matching the public key in the certificate. The peer (client) then can verify this signature using the public key of the certificate and if the verification passes the other side (server) is obviously in possession of the secret private key which means it owns the certificate.

With a client certificate used in mutual authentication the procedure is exactly the same, only with switched roles. That's why the private key is needed on the client side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I understand now why the private key is needed and you also cleared up my misunderstanding of using the term "certificate" when talking about the key exchange.